# Most effective way to build network in SQL

Tags: sql, loops, grouping

I have a small nut to crack about building a network from a simple list of relations. Currently the only way I can fathom is using recursive loops...

Assume you have a table of sender and receiver IDs that constitute a relationship between the two parties. The relation is n:m in total but every record has exactly one sender and one receiver. We now need to create a network that determines which (sub)groups within this list interact and which are independent. Hence we need to create "networks". The smallest possible example is as follows:

```
Sender | Receiver | Connection ID
-------+----------+----------------
  A.   |    B.    |      1
  B.   |    C.    |      2
  D.   |    E.    |      3
```

The intended result will create network 1 consisting of A, B, C with the corresponding connections 1 and 2 and network 2 consisting of D and E and connection 3.

The current solution is a recursive loop across the same list. Can post the SQL if helpful but likely more confusing. Would love to find out if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: The example should have been a table with just three records

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? [Modern DBMS](http://modern-sql.com/slides) support recursive queries

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

--SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp1

CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ( Sender VARCHAR(1), Receiver VARCHAR(1), ConnectionID INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp1
VALUES
('A','B',1), 
('B','C',2), 
('D','E',3)
```

--QUERY:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp2

SELECT A.Sender
    , A.Receiver
    , A.ConnectionID
    , B_Sender  = B.Sender
    , B_Receiver = B.Receiver
    , B_ConnectionID = B.ConnectionID
    INTO #Temp2
FROM   #Temp1 AS A
      LEFT OUTER JOIN #Temp1 AS B ON A.Receiver = B.Sender;


SELECT  NETWORK = ISNULL(A.Sender, '')+', '+ ISNULL(A.Receiver, '')+', '+ISNULL(A.B_Receiver, ''), 
       CONNECTION =  ISNULL(CAST(A.ConnectionID AS VARCHAR),'')+', '+ISNULL(CAST(A.B_ConnectionID AS VARCHAR),'') 
FROM #Temp2 AS A WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM #Temp2 AS B WHERE B_Sender=A.Sender  AND B_Receiver = A.Receiver AND B_ConnectionID = A.ConnectionID)
```

--RESULTS:

[image]